# Уехала навсегда девушка, которую я любил 1) и 2) так как мне шёл тогда всего

Tags: синтаксис

Уехала навсегда девушка, которую я любил 1) и 2) так как мне шёл тогда всего лишь двадцать второй год, появилось убеждение 3) я 4) потеряв свою любовь 5) остался один на всём белом свете.

На мой взгялд запятые ставятся в 4) и 5) "деепричастный оборот"

3) ставится "двоеточие" т.к. вторая часть дополняет первую

1)обособляется поэтому ставится запятая

2)ставится запятая потому что перед -> так как

Верно ли я расставил знаки препинания?

Answer (score 3):

**Уехала навсегда девушка**, которую я любил, **и**, так как мне шёл тогда всего лишь двадцать второй год, **появилось убеждение**: я, потеряв свою любовь, остался один на всём белом свете.

Запятые:
1) между главным и придаточным; 2) закрывает придаточное и ставится перед сочинительным союзом И; 3) и 4) обособляет придаточное; 5) и 6) обособляет деепричастный оборот.

Двоеточие обозначает **изъяснительные отношения** между двумя частями сложного предложения (появилось убеждение, что...).